# No sound or toast message when alarm goes off in android emulator app

Tags: java, android, audio, notifications

I am writing the basics of my alarm app that I want the user to specify the time they want the alarm to go off, then when it goes off display a toast message and play a sound until the stop the alarm. My code below allows them to set an alarm but no toast message or sound event occurs when the time specified is reached. Any help would be great, my code is below, my MainActivity.java file:

```
package com.alarm.mobilegame;

import java.util.Calendar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TimePicker myTimePicker;
Button buttonstartSetDialog;
TextView textAlarmPrompt;
TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog;
Button cancelalarm;

final static int RQS_1 = 1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textAlarmPrompt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.alarmprompt);

    buttonstartSetDialog = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startAlarm);
    buttonstartSetDialog.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
            textAlarmPrompt.setText("");
            openTimePickerDialog(false);

           }});

                cancelalarm = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel);
                cancelalarm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

           @Override
           public void onClick(View arg0) {
            cancelAlarm();
           }});

            }

private void openTimePickerDialog(boolean is24r) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this,
            onTimeSetListener, calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
            calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), is24r);
    timePickerDialog.setTitle("Set Alarm Time");

    timePickerDialog.show();
}

OnTimeSetListener onTimeSetListener = new OnTimeSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

        Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();

        calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
        calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        if (calSet.compareTo(calNow) <= 0) {
            // Today Set time passed, count to tomorrow
            calSet.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }
        setAlarm(calSet);
    }
};

private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal) {

    textAlarmPrompt.setText("\n\n***\n" + "Alarm is set "
            + targetCal.getTime() + "\n" + "***\n");

    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Receiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(),
            pendingIntent);
    }
private void cancelAlarm(){

    textAlarmPrompt.setText(
        "\n\n***\n"
        + "Alarm Cancelled! \n"
        + "***\n");

      Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Receiver.class);
      PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
      AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
      alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

     }
```

}

My Receiver.java file:

```
package com.alarm.mobilegame;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

 private static final int MY_NOTIFICATION_ID=1;
 NotificationManager notificationManager;
 Notification myNotification;
 private final String myBlog = "";

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
 Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm received!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

 Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(myBlog));
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        context, 
        0, 
        myIntent, 
        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

 myNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
   .setContentTitle("Exercise of Notification!")
   .setContentText("http://android-er.blogspot.com/")
   .setTicker("Notification!")
   .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
   .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
   .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
   .setAutoCancel(true)
   .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
   .build();

 notificationManager = 
   (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
 notificationManager.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID, myNotification);
 }
}
```

Here is my manifest file also:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.alarm.mobilegame"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.alarm.mobilegame.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/text" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <receiver android:name=".Receiver" android:process=":remote" />
</application>
</manifest>
```

Note: Eclipse shows no warnings or errors which makes me think my code isn't doing what I want it to do or think it should be doing.

Comment: I have made a minor change to code and now know that the alarm is working, changing in the manifest file <receiver android:name=".Receiver" android:process=":remote" /> to <receiver android:name="Receiver" android:process=":remote" />. However, no music is played, which I would like to repeat until user stops alarm.